# How to change the color of active TAB in a TabControl, in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol

How to change the color of active TAB in a TabControl (on FireMonkey) as shown below?

[image]

Comment: I'm away from my computer, but I believe you will want to do it by modifying the style.

Comment: The only way I have been able to change the color so far is by rightly accessing "Custom Style ..." from each TAB individually and inserting a "rectangle" control on background with property `align = Client` and `Fill.Color = MyColor`. I don't know if that's what you meant... If you remember otherwise, please let me know. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can modify the style in the TStyleBook change the appearance of the selected tab.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth: The way you suggested works, but I couldn't get the visual result as I expected, so I gave up using the TTabControl tabs and created my own tabs. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to make this happen.

1) First option is you can create ***CustomStyle***  for ***TabControl*** from ***TStyleBook*** (Style Designer).

Then you can add whatever you want to use in your custom design (***TRectangle*** is recommmended for many shape and colors).

2) I prefer to use second way for it. Set the ***TTabControl***'s ***TabPosition*** to ***None***, then add a ***TGridPanelLayout*** to where you want to add tabs in your form. After that, set your TGridPanelLayout's column count for your tab count.

Now you need to know that your each tab box should be same. Drop a ***TRectangle*** for first column then set ***Align*** to ***Client*** (All colors and inner components are depends on your choice).

Be sure that your ***TRectangle*** components ***HitTest*** parameter is ***true*** and inner components' ***HitTest*** parameter is ***false***.

Also you can handle your tab selections from ***OnClick*** event. Set each TRectangle (for tab) a Tag then connect all tabs to same OnClick event. Then you get Sender's Tag and set your ***TabControl1.ActiveTab*** from your Tag.

Comment: I got to use some of yours tips, but I couldn't get the visual result as I expected, so I gave up using the `TTabControl` tabs and created my own tabs. Even so your answer is valid so others can use it to solve the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: I always use this solution for menu, pagging and dashboard forms. Hope it works and helps you. Also you can handle your tab changing with `TGestureManager` and it helps you for swiping your tabs. In addition to my answer: use png pictures `TPicture` and use `TLabel` if you needed in your `TRectangle` items.

Comment: You can't edit the tab header color through custom style because only the body is exposed, you cannot put a trectangle in the header part through the designer (stylebook)

Comment: @user30478 maybe you can offer new solutions then. That was worked when I wrote it which was 5 years ago.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz i was just trying to validate/invalidate the point 1. Your second method should work.

Comment: @user30478 Thanks for commenting about second method. Maybe you might give your ideas at once next time. Please show them the right method if you disagree. I realized my second way still works. For that reason, you should say both. Not just "first one is wrong." If new people see your message, they might get your idea.