# Delphi TTabControl - easy way to change colour of Horizontal Line

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol

Is there an easy way to change the colour of the horizontal line that appears
when the TAB is active?

Usually it appears as Green... I use Edit Default Style to change the colour to blue/red when Text is active, but I could not find an equivalent for the Green Horizontal line?

[image: Image of TabControl]

(if can't see above Image, see [image]

Is the Green an android / windows / Delphi default?  I see some images with green shapes inside the Edit Default Style properties...

1. Can the Green horizontal line be changed to blue/red easily?
2. Can the Green horizontal line be disabled (set Invisible) easily without disabling the Active/non-active feature of the Tab text?  I suppose I can set the Tab text to non-styled, and then manually change the colour of the Tab Text... but will be less elegant

Thanks for any input.  I've checked the web for any link I can find (including [How to change the color of active TAB in a TabControl, in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836923/how-to-change-the-color-of-active-tab-in-a-tabcontrol-in-delphi))

Answer (score 0):

The style used to paint the bottom line in the tabitems is TabItemStyle.Top.ActiveLink

You can use the style designer to change which rectangle is used for ActiveLink. For instance, you could click on this property to bring up the bitmaplinks editor, and then drag the rectangle so that the bottom line is not part of ActiveLink, and then your colored line is not drawn.

Comment: is there an easier way to disable this ActiveLink, without messing with the bitmaplinks editor?  for example, diabling the style totally?  my stylelookup/stylename are both empty for the TTabControl and TTabItem but it's still showing the ActiveLink line.